# Hilbert subspaces of $B(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Apart from the one-dimensional subspaces, what are the Hilbert subspaces of $B(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

I'm not even sure if such subspaces exist.

Comment: Can you do $B(\mathbb R^2)$?

Comment: I was trying $B(\mathbb{R}^2)$. I haven't even been able to find two matrices which satisfy the parallelogram law and are not scalar multiples.

Comment: Can you write a formula for the operator norm of a $2 \times 2$ matrix?

Comment: So to clarify, $B(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the space of $n \times n$ matrices under the operator norm?  (I first interpreted it as the space of bounded functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ under the sup norm.)

Comment: Matrices in which the columns numbered $2,\dots,n$ are zero form an $n$-dimensional Euclidean subspace of $B(\mathbb R^n)$. I suspect this may be the maximal dimension.